# How to make Libreoffice autocorrect in Hirsute Hippo (21.04)

Tags: libreoffice, 21.04

Hirsute Hippo (21.04) fresh install comes with Libreoffice 7.1.2.2.
Autocorrect (Tools > autocorrect) is not working. When searching the issue, I see that it appears to be linked to various distributions of LInux (cf. [Libreoffice forum](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/293254/autocorrect-has-stopped-working/) and [Mate forum](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/autocorrect-bug-in-libreoffice/23965) Does anybody know if this issue is being dealt with? Will downgrading Libreoffice solve the problem?

Comment: I am not expert on this, but did you go to Tools ⇒ Language ⇒ For Selection (or For All Text) and select the correct language? And is the appropriate Dictionary installed (Tools ⇒ Options ⇒ Language Settings...)?

Comment: I can't reproduce. Please enter two dashes by `--` and then hit <Enter> or `-->` and then hit <Enter>. For first you will get `–` , for second your will get `→`. Trying `:alien:` with <Enter> may be fun too. `HEllo` with <Enter> normally transformed to `Hello` too. Please add reproducible method to the question.

Comment: For what @N0rbert mentioned to work, you have to have the Tools ⇒ AutoCorrect ⇒ AutoCorrect Options... ⇒ Options ⇒ [T] Use Replacement Table (while typing) ticked.

Comment: Yes, in the languages settings under "Options" the relevant dictionaries are shown to have been installed. 
@N0rbert: Yes, I get the replacements for :alien:  --> and HEllo followed by enter, but not when they are NOT followed by enter. In normal text, I want, say, a dash -- not the two hyphens, and I want double spaces to be ignored because that is what I have checked in the tools > autocorrect > autocorrect options > options, for each relevant language.

Comment: It would seem that for replacement to occur, items in the replacement table have to be followed by enter rather than by a space.

Comment: You must have all LO components be consistent. Example, if you desire Australian to be your default for region and language. Then you must use system settings to choose Australia; you must install the correct packages for Australia lexicon; for thesaurus, install the GB mythes; you must create and save an Australian document template; you must choose the correct language when spell checking the document you have.  If you receive a doc from a US person, nothing will work for spelling, until you install all the internals needed for US spelling and choose the correct spell language.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm the issue using default English language while running LibreOffice on Ubuntu 21.04 installation live media (tested on MATE, but others may be also affected). Confirmed on 21.04 minimal system with OpenBox as window manager.

I have reported this bug at LaunchPad as https://pad.lv/1926083 .

Comment: Thank you N0rbert. As you imply in your bug report, this issue also applies to other languages, for instance Norwegian.

Comment: On the bug page please mark yourself as affected by this bug and add a comment about Norwegian.